# development of a function and set of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to find the development of the function  $ e^{x^2}$
and the set of convergence.

Considering that:
$e^x= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {x^k}{k!} + R_n(x,0)$

and substituting $x$ with $x^2$ I can write
$e^{x^2}= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac {x^{2k}}{k!} + R_n(x,0)$

Now I have to prove that  $ R_n(x,0)$ tends to $0$ to say that

$e^{x^2}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^{2k}}{k!}$

and for which $x$ it happens.

please help me

Comment: It is $R_n(x^2, 0)$ after the substitution ...

Comment: ok , and if I had $R(x,x_0)$, does it become $R(x^2, {x_0}^2)$?